# Can I chain/connect liquid tags as a one-liner? Is there a separator symbol?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

This is the code which works fine in a jekyll-template:

```
{% if link.url contains 'http' %}
   {% assign domain = '' %}
{% else %}
   {% assign domain = site.url %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to make this a one-liner in liquid something like this:

```
{% if link.url contains 'http' assign domain = '' else assign domain = site.url endif %}
```

Or do I always have to use `{% %}` to separate the commands? This looks so ugly.

```
{% if link.url contains 'http' %}{% assign domain = '' %}{% else %}{% assign domain = site.url %}{% endif %}
```

Comment: It may look ugly, but it works. I don't think you can have your "one-liner" the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the output to render on one line (or fewer), in order to reduce white space, then you can use tags like `{%- if something -%}`: the additional hyphens remove all leading and trailing space.

Comment: Yeah, relatively. There is plenty info here if you want to go down the rabbit hole! https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/216